# How to calculate pace as per formula of Excel?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have two columns `time` and `distance`, their values `12:00:04 AM` and `0.0088626` respectively. In Excel I apply the following formula to find pace:

```
=IFERROR(A2/(B2*1000)*1000,0)
```

and the answer is `12:07:31 AM`.

I tried to find out pace as per above formula in PHP. I have written PHP code:

```
$dis = 0.0088626;
$time =  strtotime('12:00:04 AM');
echo date('h:i:s',strtotime(($time / ($dis * 1000) * 1000)));
```

and the answer is `1:00:00`.

Excel and PHP answers are different.

How I can I achieve this goal?

Comment: You need to convert time to an MS Excel timestamp value, not a unix timestamp... as I've already shown you once today

Comment: yes i have try but getting wrong value

Comment: `$time =  strtotime('12:00:04 AM');` is purely a unix timestamp.... where's the logic for converting this to an Excel timestamp?

Comment: i don't show in code

Comment: i have written this code  `$time =  strtotime('12:00:04 AM');
$temp_time = strtotime('00:00:00');
$time_data = ($time - $temp_time) / 86400;`

Comment: Please let me suggest if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the code I showed you earlier to convert PHP's unix timestamps to Excel serialized timestamp values to use in your equation

```
$dis = 0.0088626;

$x = strtotime("12:00:04 AM");
$y = strtotime("00:00:00");

$time = ($x - $y) / 86400;

$result = ($time / ($dis * 1000) * 1000);
```

Then once you've calculated the result, you need to convert it back from a Excel serialized timestamp value to a unix timestamp so that you can use PHP's date function

```
$result *= 86400;
echo date('h:i:s A', $result), PHP_EOL;
```

which displays the answer `12:07:31 AM`